# Как обработать браузерную кнопку назад в React?

Tags: reactjs, маршрутизация, react-router

Подскажите пожалуйста, мне нужно обработать роутинг, при переходе на страницу заказов, проверяется авторизирован пользователь или нет, если нет его редиректит на страницу логина, после того как он авторизируется его переносит на страницу заказов и если в такой ситуации нажать кнопку назад, то она вернет его на страницу login, а она в свою очередь выполнит проверку и вернет его обратно в order. Как сделать чтобы она возвращала на главную страницу, если мы возвращаемся со страницы заказов.

Answer (score 0):

после логина используйте сразу 2 перехода

```
history.push("/main");
history.push("/order");
```